# Rhomobile rake redis aborted

Tags: redis, rhomobile, rhodes

I am working my way through the RhoMobile tutorial http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnect/command-line#generate-an-application and I at the point of entering

```
rake redis:install
```

I get the following error.

```
WARNING: using the built-in Timeout class which is known to have issues when use
d for opening connections. Install the SystemTimer gem if you want to make sure
the Redis client will not hang.

See http://redis.io/ for information about redis.

Installing redis to C:\RhoStudio\redis-2.4.0;C:\dropbox\code\InstantRhodes\redis
-1.2.6-windows.
rake aborted!
Zip end of central directory signature not found

Tasks: TOP => redis:install => redis:download
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

D:\Dropbox\code\rhodes-apps\storeserver>
```

I am working on a Whindows machine, primarily using RhoStudio.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an environmental variables issue.  Also, it seems the main support forum for Rhodes is the Google Group.  Question answered here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rhomobile/b-Adx2FDMT8/discussion

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rhostudio in windows then redis is automatically installed with Rhostudio.
So no need of installing it again.